# Comparing Record Counts from a Table over Time to Trigger Alerts

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to retrieve and compare record counts from a MySQL table at two different instances. The goal is to send an email alert via a shell script if the count remains the same after 15 minutes.

Here is the shell script I'm using:

```bash
DB_user=""
DB_pass=""
DB_name=""
table_name=""

previous_count=$(mysql -u "$DB_user" -p"$DB_pass" -D "$DB_name" -N -B -e "select count(*) from "$table_name";)

latest_count=$(mysql -u "$DB_user" -p"$DB_pass" -D "$DB_name" -N -B -e "select count(*) from "$table_name";)

if [ "$latest_count" -eq "$previous_count" ]; then
  echo "Current count of records in the table remains the same from the past 15 minutes!"
else
  echo "fine"
fi
```

When I run this script, I encounter the following errors:

```bash
line 13: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You have `"select count(*) from "$table_name"`. That looks unbalanced to me. Try: `"select count(*) from $table_name"`. But surely `table_name` is assigned some value other than "", no?

Comment: Take a closer look at your `"` and then try and match them, I dont think they do. HINT You cannot use double quotes inside a double quoted literal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you are using double quotes in your script. Here's the corrected version:

```bash
DB_user=""
DB_pass=""
DB_name=""
table_name=""

previous_count=$(mysql -u "$DB_user" -p"$DB_pass" -D "$DB_name" -N -B -e "select count(*) from $table_name")

latest_count=$(mysql -u "$DB_user" -p"$DB_pass" -D "$DB_name" -N -B -e "select count(*) from $table_name")

if [ "$latest_count" -eq "$previous_count" ]; then
  echo "Current count of records in the table remains the same from the past 15 minutes!"
else
  echo "fine"
fi
```

You had extra double quotes around `$table_name`, causing the error. Remove those and your script should work fine.

#### 15-minute delay

You can add a 15-minute delay by using the `sleep` command.

```bash
DB_user=""
DB_pass=""
DB_name=""
table_name=""

previous_count=$(mysql -u "$DB_user" -p"$DB_pass" -D "$DB_name" -N -B -e "select count(*) from $table_name")

# Wait for 15 minutes
sleep 900

latest_count=$(mysql -u "$DB_user" -p"$DB_pass" -D "$DB_name" -N -B -e "select count(*) from $table_name")

if [ "$latest_count" -eq "$previous_count" ]; then
  echo "Current count of records in the table remains the same from the past 15 minutes!"
else
  echo "fine"
fi
```